# how to use Sql Views in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq

I have created views in sql how can I use in Linq query

I have get data from many tables and calculate stockIn,stockOut,StockClearence and StockRejection how can i do this by using Views.

Please any one give me the reference website for views using Linq
I developed application in c#.net. desktop application

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The same as tables. Except that you can't update, insert, delete and have entity relations.

Everything else is the same. Just drop the view on the DBML designer surface.

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined the views in you SQL Server Database, they'll appear in the Server Explorer and can be dragged and dropped onto the DBML diagram. The view(s) will not have any relation to other tables. You are suppose to create a related view for your screen requirements and the exact view will be translated by SQL Metal for the DBML file. You can bind the view and/or read it. Views only allow SELECT.

Comment: how can we use multiple table in views using join?

Comment: We'll, you'd do that in good old SQL Server Management Studio. You'd create one view with 500 tables with joins. Once you are happy with the view output, you just save it and use it in DBML file. That way, L2S doesn't need to know what the view is from the inside. However, if there be a requirement where you still need to join a view with another view or table while inside the DBML diagram, just right click somewhere and put a new association or inheritance as per requirement. That'll be a join, then.

Comment: Actually I want to increase performance of my application so i want to remove for-each loop and instead of for-each i want to add views in that. I want to fetch Banach of data with stock calculation so the performance point of view is very slow. you have any idea? for performance

Comment: We'll, from my experience, if you can create a User Defined function or Stored Procedure to do you complex calculations at SQL Server level and just bring forth nice results, then go on and write SPs/UDFs and call them in views. Remember, the SP and UDF are also supported in DBML as well. You can actually call a SP directly in your C#/VB code and pass on the parameters and relieve results. This is how I'd do it. If the calculations themselves are way too intensive even for the SQL Server, then it's the calculation's algorithm you should reconsider.